# What is the difference between quotes and brackets for pre-processor directives in C++?

Tags: c++

I am looking at a code example and notice some pre-processor directives using quotes and the others using brackets? What is the difference?

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else // Redhat Linux Version 6.0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "CamCoStr.hh"
```

Comment: `""` also look in the current directory

Comment: "also" is misleading.

Comment: @krzaq - that is not required.

Comment: What? *If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
# include < h-char-sequence> new-line*

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include